# I may be crazy for wanting a completely PvP campaign

Tags: campaign-development

So, recently I hatched the genius idea to design a free for all campaign. After about ten minutes, I said to myself this isn't going to work. Later that month I was thinking about it a little more and I came up with having about 4-5 groups of people all playing at the same time on the same map. Each group is a squad in a battle royale situation. Each DM I guess messages the hypothetical DM group chat rolls that would effect other groups and then the group reacts accordingly. For example group B does a perception roll and finds group C before they find group B. I haven't fleshed out *all* the mechanics or worked on them enough for them to be efficient or trustworthy but am I on the right track to making something like this a reality?

Comment: It’s not clear what exactly you’re asking about.  Take our [tour], we’re a focused Q&A site not a discussion forum - if you can narrow this down to a more specific question we can help you.

Comment: This looks like an idea generation question, which SE isn't useful for. However, SE is very useful if you have a specific idea in mind and you want to see if the community considers it balanced, effective, or whatever. When you have your idea more fleshed out, let us know that idea by editing your post. If it's specific enough and you ask us to assess it in a way that's not opinion-based, then we can probably help you out.

Comment: This looks like a good question for a chat forum, such as giant in playground or other similar forums.